# LINQ dependent calculation assignment

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, design-patterns

I'm using the following pattern in C#:

```
IList<foo> x = y.Select(a => new foo
{
    b = Calc1(),
    c = Calc2()
}).ToList();

foreach(foo f in x)
{
    f.d = b / c;
}
```

What I would like to do though is:

```
IList<foo> x = y.Select(a => new foo
{
    b = Calc1(),
    c = Calc2()
    d = b / c;
}).ToList();
```

So the question is: How can you modify this pattern to allow the assignment of a value that is dependent on other values being calculated during the assignment?

(Somebody will probably point out that d should be a property that does the calculation and return a value. This is a contrived example. Assume that the value of d is calculated using other values in addition to c & b which are not available later.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't re-use initialized properties in an initializer.

I like Erik's technique.  If the query expression syntax is a bother, you can use a full-on anonymous method.

```
        List<int> y = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var x = y.Select(a =>
            {
                int b = a + 1;
                int c = a + 2;
                int d = b / c;
                return new { b = b, c = c, d = d };
            });
```

Comment: No extension methods here at all. :~

Comment: What do you mean, Ray? The call to 'Select' is an Extension Method call - on IEnumerable<T>

Comment: There's an extension method used, there's a lambda expression, which gets converted to an anonymous method by the compiler...  it's all good stuff.  We don't have to label it as any one language feature.

Answer (score 8):

If you expand this to use the full LINQ syntax:

```
IList<foo> x = (from a in y
                let bq = Calc1()
                let cq = Calc2()
                select new foo {
                    b = bq,
                    c = cq, 
                    d = bq / cq
                }).ToList();
```

This will get you what you want.

There was an answer recommending you repeat your method calls (ie, d = Calc1() / Calc2()) - but I would recommend against this, considering it may be possible that Calc1() and Calc2() are expensive operations, and needlessly performing them twice may have performance implications.

Comment: Very cool solution and just as good as David's +1. I marked David's as the correct solution because it was using the extension syntax I was looking for but if I could mark both as correct I'd mark this one as well. Thanks for the help Erik!

Comment: No worries =) Glad to have been able to help.